# How to make service idempotent to eventbridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-serverless, aws-event-bridge

I have an eventbridge rule which is configured to trigger a lambda which calls an api of my app at some cron intervals (let's say every 1 hour). Eventbridge guarantees "at least once" delivery but I want that my app register the event "only once".

Does the "id" field of eventbridge event structure change for multiple events of a single invocation? (See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-events-structure.html)

I mean if for 1 invocation, 2 events are generated at 01:00:00.000 and 01:00:00.001 (hh:mm:ss) then will the "id" field remain same or different for both. If it will be different is there any way to know if those 2 are duplicate events at my app?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider switching to https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/scheduler/?nc1=h_ls which gives you additional context attributes to detect duplicate invocations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/managing-schedule-context-attributes.html (`<aws.scheduler.attempt-number>`). Retried attempts will have different `<aws.scheduler.execution-id>`.

Note that Lambda invocation is async which may lead to additional invocations from the Lambda side with the same event. So you also need to check for the same `<aws.scheduler.execution-id>` to detect duplicates.

Comment: If "Retried attempts will have different `<aws.scheduler.execution-id>`", then I'm not sure how I can just use `<aws.scheduler.attempt-number>` to check if I have already processed the event at lambda. It could be a genuine retry from eventbridge. Ex- event 1 with id=111,retry-attempt=1 was fired from eventbridge to lambda. This event got dropped due to some network issues and another event was fired with id=222, retry-attempt=2. If I see retry-attempt=2 here and assume that it is a duplicate event, then I will be in the wrong and I'll miss a genuine event I've not seen before.

Comment: > This event got dropped due to some network issues

Lambda provides at-least-once semantics. If the event was accepted by Lambda, you wouldn't see retry-attempt=2.